# Are questions about grammatical concepts on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

We got a question about (I think) grammar: [Present perfect v. present perfect progressive (case)](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/569/13).

As of this writing, the question has a couple of **Unclear what you're asking** votes, as the specific question is a bit unclear.

But assuming we can get past that, and for future questions, do we want to address general grammatical questions here?  Is asking about "present perfect" appropriate (assuming a language-agnostic question), for instance?

Comment: I'm assuming such a question would involve grammatical concepts that can apply to more than one language at a time or else be a "how to go from L1 to L2 grammar" kind of question.

Comment: @brandaemon: So do we want to address general grammatical questions here? That's the question.

Comment: I'm not sure how many would be applicable for more than one language. Even if some were generally, there would be per-language exceptions.  I suppose learning strategies could be similar though.